# Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Student' and 'int'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I tried making index var also still it gives the same error

```cs
public void UpdateStudent(int rollNo, Student updatedStudent)
{
    var index = _list.FirstOrDefault(s => s.RollNo == rollNo);

    if (index != -1)
    {
        index.Name = updatedStudent.Name;
        index.RollNo = updatedStudent.RollNo;
        index.Marks = updatedStudent.Marks;
        index.Branch = updatedStudent.Branch;
        index.Location = updatedStudent.Location;
    }
}
```

I have tried changing it type

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` returns the item from the list, not the index of the item, you should check with `item !=null`

Comment: What do you expect `_list.FirstOrDefault` to return? It sounds like you're *expecting* it to return an integer index... that's not the case. (If you *are* expecting it to return an integer, what do you expect an assignment to `index.Name` to do?)

Comment: The error seems clear. `index` is not an integer. Maybe you want `if (index != null)`? Since FirstOrDefault returns null if nothing is found.

Comment: Your `_list` contains students, not indexes. So `FirstOrDefault`  returns the first `Student` matching your condition, or `null`, since that is the default value for reference types like classes. So change the variable from `index` to `student` and it's type from `var` to `Student`(helps to understand), then check if the `student != null`. Oh, also rename `_list` to `_studentList`.

Comment: that's why you should not use var if the type is not obvious. if you wouldn't have used var you would have to think about the returned type.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions#implicitly-typed-local-variables

Answer (score 3):

`FirstOrDefault` returns the item from the list, not the index of the item!

you should check with `item!=null` like so :

```cs
public void UpdateStudent(int rollNo, Student updatedStudent)
{
    var item = _list.FirstOrDefault(s => s.RollNo == rollNo);
    if (item != null)
    {
        item.Name = updatedStudent.Name;
        item.RollNo = updatedStudent.RollNo;
        item.Marks = updatedStudent.Marks;
        item.Branch = updatedStudent.Branch;
        item.Location = updatedStudent.Location;
    }
}
```